# How to get Email.send to send emails in the future (7 days, 14 days from now, etc)

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, momentjs

I need to send email reminders to people in the future. I have implemented MomentJS and I can get dates I'd need my email to send, I just couldn't find anything in meteor docs for Email.send(options) to have anything there. Is there a different package you can recommend?

Here is some of my code as per @richsilv 's advice

createTransfer.js (client)

```
Template.createTransfer.events({
  'submit form': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    Transfers.insert(transfer, function (error, id) {
      if (error) {
        showError(error);
      } else {
        Session.set('files');
        showAlert('Transfers sent!');
        transfer._id = id;
        Meteor.call('sendEmail', transfer);
        scheduleEmail(transfer); // send reminder email
        Router.go('viewTransfer', {_id: id});
      }
    });
    // scheduleEmail(transfer);


    console.log(transfer);

function scheduleEmail(transfer) {

  if (transfer.invoice.due == "7 Days"){
    console.log('its due in 7 days');
    if (moment(transfer.date).add(7, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
      Meteor.call('sendMail',transfer);
      }
  } else if (transfer.invoice.due == "14 Days") {
    if (moment(transfer.date).add(14, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
      Meteor.call('sendMail',transfer);
    }
  } else if (transfer.invoice.due == "30 Days") {
    if (moment(transfer.date).add(30, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
      Meteor.call('sendMail',transfer);
    }
  } else if (transfer.invoice.due == "90 Days") {
    if (moment(transfer.date).add(90, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
      Meteor.call('sendMail',transfer);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('need to initiate cron!');
    var thisId = FutureEmails.insert(transfer);
    console.log('inserted into db');
    Meteor.call('addCronMail',thisId, transfer);
  }

}
```

methods.js (lib)

```
Meteor.methods({

  sendMail: function(transfer) {

    check([transfer.senderEmail,
      transfer.recipientEmail,
      transfer.message,
      // transfer.invoice.total
      ], [String]);

      // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
      // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
      this.unblock();

      transfer.url = Meteor.absoluteUrl() +'transfer/' + transfer._id;

      var template = 'invoice-due';

      Email.send({
        to: transfer.recipientEmail,
        bcc: transfer.senderEmail,
        from: transfer.senderEmail,
        subject: transfer.senderEmail + ' sent you files!',
        html: Handlebars.templates[template](transfer)
      });

    },

    addCronMail: function(id, transfer) {

      SyncedCron.add({
        name: id,
        schedule: function(parser) {
          return parser.recur().on(transfer.date).fullDate();
        },
        job: function() {
          sendMail(transfer);
          FutureEmails.remove(id);
          SyncedCron.remove(id);
          return id;
        }
      });

    }
});
```

cron.js (server)

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  FutureEmails.find().forEach(function(mail) {
    if (moment(mail.date).format("MMM Do YY") == moment(new Date()).format("MMM Do YY")) {
      sendMail(mail)
    } else {
      addCronMail(mail._id, mail);
    }
  });
  SyncedCron.start();

});
```

Comment: You need to write cron jobs. Please google for the cron jobs.

Comment: The package [Synced-Cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) is what you need - it's the canonical Meteor cron management tool.

Comment: @richsilv from my understanding, cron is a repetitive system. in my case, I have a user sending another user an invoice with a due date for it in the future (a couple of options). then i'd want to send the user a reminder email that their payment duedate is coming up. so for example if im sending an invoice today with a due date of 14 days from now, id want that person to get an email 14 days from now. is cron something that will work in my dynamic scenario?

Comment: i don't want it to be reoccurring, i just want it to run once in the future per invoice

Comment: @sdybskiy - I don't know of anything that does what you're asking for out of the box, but per sudarshan's suggestion, maybe a cron job that will call your process and check if there's any emails to send, then you can send them at that point?

Comment: Keep in mind that your server will perhaps be restarted during this period. You do not want to lose that reminder email so you must persist the scheduled sending date in the DB. Now use Cron to check hourly (or daily) for all DB entries that are due today and are not marked as `reminderSent` (or `paid`) yet. Don't even think about using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

Comment: Totally agree with Stephan.  Store your email send dates in a server-side collection (with the relevant email details), and then you can have a startup job which adds all of the future send dates in the collection to a SyncedCron (as a backup in case of reboot - they should be added at inception too).  Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @richsilv an example would be great! thanks for all your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, although note that this is *not* tested, so you might have to play around with it.

```
$ meteor add percolatestudio:synced-cron
```

Then something like this on the server:

```
FutureEmails = new Meteor.Collection('future_emails'); // server-side only

// "details" should be an object containing a date, plus required e-mail details (recipient, content, etc.)

function sendMail(details) {

    Email.send({
        from: details.from,
        to: details.to,
        etc....
    });

}

function addCronMail(id, details) {

    SyncedCron.add({
        name: id,
        schedule: function(parser) {
            return parser.recur().on(details.date).fullDate();
        },
        job: function() {
            sendMail(details);
            FutureEmails.remove(id);
            SyncedCron.remove(id);
            return id;
        }
    });

}

function scheduleEmail(details) { 

    if (details.date < new Date()) {
        sendMail(details);
    } else {
        var thisId = FutureEmails.insert(details);
        addCronMail(thisId, details);       
    }

}

Meteor.startup(function() {

    FutureEmails.find().forEach(function(mail) {
        if (mail.date < new Date()) {
            sendMail(mail)
        } else {
            addCronMail(mail._id, mail);
        }
    });
    SyncedCron.start();

});
```

Then just call `scheduleEmail(details)` whenever you want to schedule a new mail.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: all of the above code goes on server? and then `scheduleEmail(details)` goes, for example, where someone is clicking to submit the invoice?

Comment: it's all server code, so yes.  `scheduleEmail` must also be run from the server, so it should be inside an appropriately secure method that you can call from the client.

Comment: i am getting the following client error @richsilv
`Error invoking Method 'addCronMail': Internal server error [500]`

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: `Exception while invoking method 'addCronMail' TypeError: Object Mon Dec 15 2014 14:16:03 GMT-0500 (EST) has no method 'getTime'` @richsilv

Comment: I think that happens if you try to add a job for a time that's already passed.  Have a look at [this](http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/scheduling-events-in-the-future-with-meteor/) - I wrote a blog post about it, which includes contingency for past dates (which will run immediately).

Comment: i've updated the question with my file structure, i'm probably doing it wrong

Comment: It won't let me add more comments here! But you can see on my solution that there is a check that the date isn't in the past in `scheduleMail` that isn't in your code.

Comment: where do i perform the check to see if it's been 7 days and if it has, send out the email

Comment: @sdybskiy getTime() is a method of a javascript date object. Perhaps the string value you passed into the parser, using your variable transfer.date was not in the correct format new Date(Y, M, D, h, m, s); to allow javascript to create a date object from it?